# How to fix "SSL error: certificate verify failed"

Tags: terminal

I started a bash code that tries to download a file via `axel`, but when the script is about to download the file, it crashes and the error `SSL error: certificate verify failed`.

Can someone please help me with that, like adding an exception via command-line?

Part of the code:

```
axel ${EXTRAARGS} --alternate "https://build.nethunter.com/kalifs/kalifs-20171013/kalifs-armhf-minimal.tar.xz "
```

Other variables were already declared.
The result is:

```
Initializing download: https://build.nethunter.com/kalifs/kalifs-20171013/kalifs-armhf-minimal.tar.xz<br>
SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

Thanks anyway.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we can see how you're performing the download. Paste the full script (with any sensitive data removed if needed, of course).

Comment: Please, also check ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and ["How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). You are going to get better results by following the tips present on those documents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try `man axel`? From the `man` page:

```
   --insecure, -k
          Do not verify the SSL certificate. Only use this if 
          you are getting certificate errors and you are sure
          of the sites authenticity.
```